# How come Zera asks Cornelius if he likes chocolate?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, beneath-the-planet-of-the-apes

In “Beneath The Planet of The Apes", Zera asks Cornelius if he likes chocolate, then says

> “No, of course you don't... ...But I do"

Why?

Comment: Out-of-universe: seems like something the writer came up with to try to humanize  not just the characters, but their relationship, despite their obvious chimp-ishness. In the first (original) movie, there were quite a few moments where simians acted like stereotypical simians in vocalizations, gestures, and general movement. This introduces a bit of contrast and "evolution".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As they walk through the door, they're having an argument, one that they've had before, presumably one they've had many times. She decides to make a cake to try to assuage her anger and asks him if he'd like chocolate icing. When he says that he doesn't like chocolate (something that she half-remembers) she basically says

> "*well f-ck you, we're having it anyway **because I like it** and I'm in a bad mood with you and the world in general".*

Comment: I think your answer is more emotional than is necessary.